# How does DBAL read data that ORM inserts but has not yet “flush”?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, dbal

For historical reasons, my pattern of running databases using Symfony is mixed. That is, the query uses DBAL and the insert uses ORM. Now you need to write a lot of data to the database. The `flush` in ORM can help me achieve business at the lowest cost.

All `flush` operations have been removed from the project. Put it in the `__destruct` of the `controller`.
However, doing so will cause DBAL to not find the latest changed data. Of course, these data ORMs can be obtained normally.
This is a very difficult problem. I hope to get guidance.

```php
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $model = new CompanyModel();
        $model->install(['company_name' => '1234']);
        $model->update(['company_name' => 'abcd'], $model->lastInsertId);
    }
}

class CompanyModel extends BaseController
{

    public function validate($data, $id = false)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        if(empty($id)){
            $this->company_class = new Company();
        }else{
            if(!$this->is_exist($id)){
                return false;
            }

            $this->company_class = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Company::class)->find($id);
        }

        if(array_key_exists('company_name', $data)){
            $this->company_class->setCompanyName($data['company_name']);
        }

        if(self::$error->validate($this->company_class)){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function insert($data)
    {
        if(!$this->validate($data)){
            return false;
        }

        $this->company_class->setCreateAt(new \DateTime());

        $this->entityManager->persist($this->company_class);
        //$this->entityManager->flush();

        $this->lastInsertId = $this->company_class->getId();

        return true;
    }

    public function update($data, $id)
    {
        if(empty($id)){
            self::$error->setError('param id is not null');
            return false;
        }

        if(!$this->validate($data, $id)){
            return false;
        }

        $this->company_class->setUpdateAt(new \DateTime());

        //$this->entityManager->flush();

        return true;
    }

    public function is_exist($id)
    {
        return $this->get('database_connection')->fetchColumn('...');
    }


}
```

The final result of executing `indexAction` `company_name` is `1234`; `$ model-> update()` was not executed successfully. The reason is that the `$this-> is_exist()` method that took the DBAL query did not find the ORM insert but did not `flush` the message.

Unchanging conditions，run

```php
$this->entityManager->getRepository(Company::class)->find($id);
```

Is successful。

Comment: In order to  put flush method in __destruct(). Is it working for you?

Comment: you could try `beginTransaction`/`commit` to wrap it all in a transaction, and flush immediately after changes. this might slightly improve performance. however, it appears your pattern sucks and you shouldn't mix. the ORM is like a staging area, and if you're working correctly, you don't need an id to make it work within the orm. mixing it with dbal is a problem that might cause inconsistencies at some point and a code smell and should be refactored asap. (I would give suggestions, but you provide too few code samples to show where the dbal causes the problems)

Comment: @Jakumi thank you very much. I perfected my problem.

Comment: @MiteshVasava thank you very much. I perfected my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the entity manager or dbal, as far as I can tell, but the usage of an anti-pattern, which I would call ... entanglement. What you should strive for is **separation of concerns**. Essentially: Your "CompanyModel" is an insufficient and bad wrapper for the EntityManager and/or EntityRepository.

1. **No object** should know about the entity manager. It should only be concerned with holding the data.
2. The entity manager should be concerned with persistence and ensuring integrity.
3. The controller is meant to orchestrate one "action", that can be adding one company, editing one company, batch-importing/updatig many companies.
4. Services can be implemented, when actions become to business-logic-heavy or when functionality is repeated.

(Note: the following code samples could be made *way more elegant* with using all the features that symfony provide, like ParamConverters, the Form component, the Validation component, I usually wouldn't write code this way, but I assume everything else would go way over your head - no offence.)

#### handling actions in the controller

controller actions (or service actions, really) are when you look at your problem from the task perspective. Like "I want to update that object with this data"). That's when you fetch/create that object, then give it the data.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class BaseController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function addAction() {
        $company = new Company(['name' => '1234']); // initial setting in constructor
        $this->em->persist($company);

        // since you have the object, you can do any changes to it.
        // just change the object
        $company->update(['name' => 'abcd']); // <-- don't need id

        // updates will be flushed as well!
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    public function editAction($id, $newData) {
        $company = $this->em->find(Company::class, $id);
        if(!$company) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException();
        }
        $company->update($newData);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    // $companiesData should be an array of arrays, each containing 
    // a company with an id for update, or without an id for creation
    public function batchAction(array $companiesData) {
        foreach($companies as $companyData) {
            if($companyData['id']) {
                // has id -> update existing company
                $company = $this->em->find(Company::class, $companyData['id']);
                //// optional: 
                // if(!$company) { // id was given, but company does not exist
                //     continue;   // skip 
                //     //  OR 
                //     $company = new Company($companyData); // create
                //     //  OR
                //     throw new \Exception('company not found: '.$companyData['id']);
                // }
                $company->update($companyData);
            } else {
                // no id -> create new company
                $company = new Company($companyData);
                $this->em->persist($company);
            }
        }
        $this->em->flush(); // one flush.
    }
}
```

the base controller should handle creating objects, and persisting it, so very basic business logic. some would argue, that some of those operations should be done in an adapted Repository for that class, or should be encapsulated in a Service. And they would be right, generally.

#### the entity handles it's internal state

Now, the `Company` class handles its own properties and tries to stay consistent. You just *have* to make some assumptions here. First of all: the object itself shouldn't care if it exists in the database or not. it's not its purpose! it should handle itself. Separation of concerns! The functions inside the Company entity should concern simple business logic, that concerns its INNER state. It doesn't need the database, and it should not have any reference to the database, it only cares about it's fields.

```
class Company {

    /**
     * all the database fields as public $fieldname;
     */
    // ...

    /**
     * constructor for the inital state. You should never want 
     * an inconsistent state!
     */
    public function __construct(array $data=[]) {
        $this->validate($data); // set values
        if(empty($this->createAt)) {
            $this->createAt = new \DateTime();
        }
    }

    /**
     * update the data
     */
    public function update(array $data) {
        $this->validate($data); // set new values
        $this->updateAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function validate(array $data) {
        // this is simplified, but you can also validate 
        // here and throw exceptions and stuff
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

#### some notes

Now, there should be NO use case, where you get an object to persist and at the same time an update - with an id - that refers to the new object ... unless that object was given the id beforehand! HOWEVER. If you persist an object, that has an ID and you call `$this->em->find(Company::class, $id)` you would get that object back.

if you have many relations, there are *always* good ways to solve this problem without destroying separation of concerns! you should never inject an entity manager into an entity. the entity should not manage its own persistence! nor should it manage the persistence of linked objects. handling persistence is the purpose of the entity manager or entity repository. you should never need a wrapper around an object just to handle that object. be careful not to mix responsibilities of services, entities (objects) and controllers. In my example code, I have merged services and controllers, because in simple cases, it's good enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed instructions. I will learn from your suggestions and re-architect my code. But for now, for historical reasons, I tend not to make a thorough revision. Of course, such confusing code still needs to pay the price.

Comment: I realized that there might be no solution or no need to solve this problem. Because I collected opinions in many places. Finally, I found that my insert and edit operations in the Model did not clear the cache in time. This can cause the cache to take up a lot of time. So I put "flush" back into the model and added "$this-> entityManager-> clear();" The speed of batch inserts is significantly improved.